What is the "strange" thing that God does in Isaiah 28:21?
I find no other Bible references to God performing "strange" acts.

Isa 28:21 - For the LORD will rise up as at Mount Perazim. He will
rouse Himself as in the Valley of Gibeon, to do His work, His
strange work, and to perform His task, His disturbing task.


The answer to the OP's question is found in the preceding verses which describe God's final destruction of the wicked.  Such wicked are described as those:

who have made a covenant with death (ie, to try an avoid it)
who have made an agreement with she'ol/grave (ie, to try an avoid it)

But, said, God (V18a), "Your covenant with death will be dissolved, and your agreement with She'ol will not stand."  Indeed, God predicts that when the end arrives:

(V18b) - When the overwhelming scourge passes through, you will be trampled by it.
(V19a) - As often as it passes through, it will carry you away;

Isaiah then says, (V19b): "The understanding of this message will bring sheer terror."
MacLaren, in commenting upon this passage says this:

The consequences of sin are God’s work. The miseries consequent on sin
are self-inflicted, but they are also God’s judgments on sin. We may
say that sin automatically works out its results, but its results
follow by the will of God on account of sin.
That work is a necessity arising from the nature of God. It is foreign
to His heart but not to His nature. God is both ‘the light of Israel’
for blessing, and ‘a consuming fire.’ The two opposite effects are
equally the result of the contact of God and man. Light pains a
diseased eye and gladdens a sound one. The sun seen through a mist
becomes like a ball of red-hot iron. The whole revelation of God
becomes a pain to an unloving soul.
But God’s very love compels Him to punish.

For those who refuse to accept God's gracious love and offer of free salvation, final destruction is, effectively what they choose and thus, the LORD calls this work, "His strange work - His disturbing task"

The reference to Mt. Perezim and the Valley of Gibeon harkens back to the story of Joshua, when God reportedly made the sun stood still, a strange deed for certain. We have a variety of interpretations to choose from. Turning to Jewish sources, according to Aggadat Bereshit 77:3:

Just as the sun stood still in Gibeon and the moon in the Valley of
Aijalon (Joshua 10:12), so too will the Valley of Gibeon tremble
(Isaiah 28:21). Why? In order to perform His strange work and carry
out His task (Isaiah 28:21).

Rashi, however, interprets the strange deed as being done by the people whom God punishes:

Just as the mountains quaked when the
glory of the Lord was revealed on the day of King Uzziah, (supra.
6:4,) and as the miracles He performed for Joshua in the valley of
Gibeon (Jos. 10:12f)...
so shall He be revealed to punish those who perform (strange deeds,
strange are their deeds, and those who worship pagan deities, strange
is their worship).

Ibn Ezra, on the other hand, notes that the geographical location mentioned in the verse witnessed sever miraculous interventions by God. He sees God's work in this case as "strange" because this time it will be Israel, not her enemies, whom God punishments.

As in mount Perazim, known by the wars of David (2 Sam. 5:20); the place was called בעל פרצים place of breaches, because the Philistines
were suddenly defeated there in a miraculous way.
As in the valley of Gibeon (Jos. 10:12), where sun and moon stood still. That He may do His work, His strange work. In the same way God
will make a strange war against Israel, such as was never heard of
before.

